# Buffer process in polygon using GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, shapefile, polygon, vector

I am trying to decrease the size of a polygon so to avoid having mixels. Thus, I use the GDAL function buffer:

```
distance = -5
bufferedGeometry= initialGeometry.Buffer(distance)
```

In addition, the geometry is in 3857 Projection.

Does -5 mean -5 meters for each point of the polygon's ring?

How does the buffer process takes place?

Comment: Please do **not** ever use EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) to carry out any sort of distance related analysis. The longitude (X) axis is distorted to infinity as you move north or south of the Equator.

Comment: @IanTurton thanks for the quick reply. So, what do you recommend for projection regarding apps with distance calculations? 4326?

Comment: a local project suitable for your data set

Comment: @IanTurton thanks! I will try a local one. However, do you have any clue on how the Buffer function works?

Comment: Basically it is sufficient to know it works, if you want to know exactly you need to dig through GDAL to GEOS to JTS (https://github.com/locationtech/jts/) and read the source code.

Comment: ESRI has images about how buffers are created https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/how-buffer-analysis-works.htm . Negative buffer can only be used with polygons and then the offsets are decreasing the polygon - outer ring is squeezed and holes are made bigger.